# Segmentation Fault in Client File Transfer

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm getting a segmentation fault when I run this file transfer program, and cant seem to find the problem after hours of looking at it. I tried to include only the relevant code involved. The program splits the requested file into chunks (2 in this example), and then sends those separate file chunks to the other client. I beleive the segmentation fault occurs during the sending/receiving file part of the code:

```
while(((bytes_sent = sendfile(peer_socket_server, fd, &off, SIZE)) > 0) && (bytes_remaining > 0)){
    printf("bytes sent: %d\n", bytes_sent);
    bytes_remaining -= bytes_sent;
}

while(((bytes_received = recv(peer_socket_server, data, SIZE, 0)) > 0) && (bytes_remaining > 0)){
    printf("bytes recv: %d\n", bytes_received);
    fwrite(data, sizeof(char), bytes_received, fp);
    bytes_remaining -= bytes_received;
```

}

I put in some print statements to check what I'm receiving:

```
    recv newfilename: file1_chunk0.txt
    recv newfilesize: 1024
    bytes recv: 512
    bytes recv: 512
    recv newfilename: 
    recv newfilesize: 1024
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My second client is successfully downloading the first chunk, but the second chunk file should be file1_chunk1.txt, which is not being received/downloaded. I'm reusing the file transfer code above from a simple file transfer program that I wrote which worked, which is why I'm confused why this isnt working.

CODE:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "shared.h"
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 512
#define NUMPEERS 2
#define CHUNKSIZE 1024

void SendFileToPeer();
void* GetFileFromPeer(void* pstruct);

typedef struct thread_args{
    int peer_port_server;
    char *filename;
    int chunks;
    int offset;
    int filesize;
} astruct;


int peer_socket, peer_port;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int chunks;
    int filesize = 2048;
    int peercount = 1;
    int peers[1] = {8002};
    char filename[SIZE] = "file1.txt";

    chunks = filesize / CHUNKSIZE;
    chunks = chunks / peercount;

    pthread_t threads[NUMPEERS];
    astruct argstruct[NUMPEERS];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMPEERS; i++){
        if(peers[i] != 0 ){
            argstruct[i].peer_port_server = peers[i];
            argstruct[i].filename = strdup(filename);
            argstruct[i].chunks = chunks;
            argstruct[i].offset = i;
            argstruct[i].filesize = filesize;
            pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, GetFileFromPeer, &argstruct[i]);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < NUMPEERS; i++){
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}


void* GetFileFromPeer(void* pstruct){
    int peer_port_server;
    char filename[SIZE];
    char newfilename[600];
    int chunks;
    int offset;
    int filesize;
    int newfilesize;
    astruct *argstruct = (astruct *)pstruct;

    peer_port_server = argstruct->peer_port_server;
    strcpy(filename, argstruct->filename);
    free(argstruct->filename);
    chunks = argstruct->chunks;
    offset = argstruct->offset;
    filesize = argstruct->filesize;

    //Connect to peer server to download file
    struct sockaddr_in peer_socket_server_addr;
    int peer_socket_server;
    int peer_port_t;

    peer_socket_server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (peer_socket_server < 0) {
        printf("Error creating socket dest\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    peer_socket_server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    peer_socket_server_addr.sin_port = htons(peer_port_server);
    peer_socket_server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (connect(peer_socket_server, (struct sockaddr *)&peer_socket_server_addr, sizeof(peer_socket_server_addr)) < 0) {
        printf("Error connecting to peer server\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    recv(peer_socket_server, &peer_port_t, sizeof(int), 0);
    printf("Connected to peer server on port %d\n", peer_port_t);

    FILE *fp;
    int bytes_remaining;
    int bytes_received;
    char data[SIZE];

    send(peer_socket_server, filename, SIZE, 0);
    send(peer_socket_server, &chunks, sizeof(int), 0);
    send(peer_socket_server, &offset, sizeof(int), 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < chunks; i++){
        recv(peer_socket_server, newfilename, 600, 0);
        printf("recv newfilename: %s\n", newfilename);
        fp = fopen(newfilename, "w");

        recv(peer_socket_server, &newfilesize, sizeof(int), 0);
        printf("recv newfilesize: %d\n", newfilesize);
        bytes_remaining = newfilesize;
        while(((bytes_received = recv(peer_socket_server, data, SIZE, 0)) > 0) && (bytes_remaining > 0)){
            printf("bytes recv: %d\n", bytes_received);
            fwrite(data, sizeof(char), bytes_received, fp);
            bytes_remaining -= bytes_received;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    close(peer_socket_server);
}

void SendFileToPeer(){
    struct sockaddr_in peer_socket_server_addr;
    int peer_socket_server;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(peer_socket_server_addr);

    //Loop for multiple peers to connect
    while(1)
    {
        char filename[SIZE];
        int chunks;
        int offset;
        int byte_offset;
        int filesize;
        char newfilename[600];
        char tempfilename[SIZE];
        int bytes_sent = 0;
        off_t off = 0;
        int bytes_remaining;
        FILE *fp1, *fp2;
        char buf[SIZE];
        int remaining;
        int fd;
        struct stat filestat;

        peer_socket_server = accept(peer_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&peer_socket_server_addr, &len);

        send(peer_socket_server, &peer_port, sizeof(int), 0);
        printf("\nPeer %d has connected\n", peer_socket_server);

        recv(peer_socket_server, filename, SIZE, 0);
        recv(peer_socket_server, &chunks, sizeof(int), 0);
        recv(peer_socket_server, &offset, sizeof(int), 0);

        printf("Sending file %s to peer %d\n", filename, peer_socket_server);

        offset = offset * chunks;
        byte_offset = offset * CHUNKSIZE;
        strncpy(tempfilename, filename, SIZE);
        tempfilename[strlen(tempfilename)-4] = '\0';

        fp1 = fopen(filename, "r");
        for (int i = 0; i < chunks; i++){
            sprintf(newfilename, "%s_chunk%d.txt", tempfilename, i+offset);
            send(peer_socket_server, newfilename, 600, 0);
            printf("sent file: %s\n", newfilename);

            fp2 = fopen(newfilename, "w");
            remaining = CHUNKSIZE;
            fseek(fp1, byte_offset, SEEK_SET);
            while(fread(buf, SIZE, 1, fp1) != 0){
                if(remaining > 0){
                    fwrite(buf, SIZE, 1, fp2);
                    remaining -= SIZE;
                }
            }
            byte_offset += CHUNKSIZE;
            fclose(fp2);

            //Send file
            fd = open(newfilename, O_RDONLY); 
            fstat(fd, &filestat);
            filesize = filestat.st_size;
            bytes_remaining = filesize;

            send(peer_socket_server, &filesize, sizeof(int), 0);
            printf("sent size: %d\n", filesize);

            while(((bytes_sent = sendfile(peer_socket_server, fd, &off, SIZE)) > 0) && (bytes_remaining > 0)){
                printf("bytes sent: %d\n", bytes_sent);
                bytes_remaining -= bytes_sent;
            }
            close(fd);
        }
        fclose(fp1);
        close(peer_socket_server);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a quick look, try to add some error checking. I did not see any. If `recv` returns zero, you get an infinite loop.

Comment: Read [ask] and post an [mcve].

Comment: @user14063792468 I checked the return value and in the second loop of the for loop, its only receiving 92 bytes instead of 600, and then `recv`  of newfilesize is returning 0.

Comment: Start by using a debugger. It will tell you instantly the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault and that is the minimum debugging you should have done already and should post in the question. Can also use the debugger to examine the state of the code at and leading up to the seg fault.

Comment: The problem is fixed. The issue was that I had to move `off_t off = 0;` inside the for loop to reset it to 0 after every file.

Comment: So the issue was that you did not modify `off` variable after you do a `sendfile`? You can post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had to move `off_t off = 0;` inside the for loop to reset it to 0 after every `sendfile`